# PHP limit the loop based on available array element

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I created the **available seat** with a ***for*** loop below:

```
<?php

$seats = 7;

for ($i=1; $i <= $seats; $i++) {

?>

<div class='col-xs-6'>
  <div class='well text-center' id='<?php echo $i ?>'>
    Seat No: <?php echo $i ?>
  </div>
</div>

<?php

}

?>
```

And I want to add a ***booked*** class if the `$i` variable matches with the `$k` variables which taken from the ***booked seat*** array elements below:

```
$booked_seat = array('1','4','5','6','7');
```

the result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 6
    [4] => 7
)
```

So I did this:

```
<?php

$seats = 7;

for ($i=1; $i <= $seats; $i++) {

?>

<div class='col-xs-6'>
  <div class='well text-center <?php echo ($i == $booked_seat[$i-1]) ? 'booked' : '' ?>' id='<?php echo $i ?>'>
    Seat No: <?php echo $i ?>
  </div>
</div>

<?php

}

?>
```

And i get the offset Error because the `$booked_seat` is not much as the `$seats` loop, how to limit the loop so it will not offset?

Thank you before

Comment: Use [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) to check if the index is defined before trying to access it.

Comment: What are you checking for in `$booked_seat`? Are you looking for `$i` as a value or if there is any value at index `$i`?

Comment: I think it would just be easier to create another array that is in length `$seats` and each place in the array is either true or false

Comment: alternatively you could have another index, say $j, that marks your place in the booked_seat array and you advance it only when you hit a booked seat. This implies that booked_seat must be sorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$seats = 7;

for ($i=1; $i <= $seats; $i++) {


?>

<div class='col-xs-6'>
  <div class='well text-center <?php echo (in_array($i, $booked_seat)) ? "booked" : "" ?>' id='<?php echo $i ?>'>
    Seat No: <?php echo $i ?>
  </div>
</div>

<?php

}

?>
```

warning: code is untested.

Answer (score 1):

You could always flip the `$booked_seat` array, then test for the existence of the array element using `isset()`.  Something like this:

```
<?php

$seats = 7;
$booked_seat = array('1','4','5','6','7');
$booked_a = array_flip($booked_seat);

for ($i=1; $i <= $seats; $i++) {
  printf("seat: %d%s\n", $i, isset($booked_a[$i]) ? " booked" : "");
}
```

(This was my test, you can add your HTML to suit.)

Example: http://3v4l.org/5npsm

Answer (score 0):

You should use the method sizeof().

So:

> $num_seats = sizeof($seats);

Then a for loop with this.

> for($i = 0; $i < $num_seats; $i++){
>      //code
>   }